# Group by and most recent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm grouping items like that:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @games = Game.all
    @game_days = Game.all.group_by { |g| g.created_at.strftime("%B, %d") }
  end
```

The problem is that sorts items by day like that :

- Yesterday (item1, item2...)
- Today (item1, item2...)

And i want to invert sorting like that:

- Today (item1, item2...)
- Yesterday (item1, item2...)

...

How can i do ???
Cheers!

Comment: Check [group_date](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem in combination with [by_star](https://github.com/radar/by_star) gem they will save you a lot of time. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
Game.order("created_at DESC").group_by { |g| g.created_at.strftime("%B, %d") }
```

You can order by any column in any direction.

There is also a `reverse_order` method which you can use instead of ordering Descending.

```
Game.order("created_at ASC").reverse_order.group_by { |g| g.created_at.strftime("%B, %d") }
```

The result is the same, just what approach you like more.

Cheers

Comment: @HenriCHEVALLIER Could you please accept the answer ? Thanks !